# 'Maybe git-rebase is broken'

Tags: git, msysgit

### 3rd Update

More information:

- commands in the git-bash shell work as expected

  - in the git-bash shell, Git\bin\git.exe is called
  - Git\bin is where sh.exe lives
- in PowerShel (or cmd, or tcc), Git\cmd\git.exe is called
- even after adding Git\bin to the PATH (after Git\cmd), the scripts don't work

Very frustrating...

### 2nd Update

It appears all the git commands implemented by .exe files work: git-fetch.exe, git-merge.exe, git-push.exe, etc.

It appears all the commands implemented as scripts to *not* work:

```
Git\libexec\git-core\git-pull
Git\libexec\git-core\git-rebase
```

etc.  So, whatever git.exe is calling to run the `libexec\git-core` scripts appears to be farkled...

### 1st update

Here we go again...  "git pull" has gone sideways (pretty sure it was working yesterday):

```
I:\Work\bitbucket\PluralSight\proj1 [work2]> git stat
On branch work2   nothing to commit, working directory clean
I:\Work\bitbucket\PluralSight\proj1 [work2]> git fetch
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org':
I:\Work\bitbucket\PluralSight\proj1 [work2]> git pull
*fatal: 'pull' appears to be a git command, but we
were not able to execute it. Maybe git-pull is broken?*
I:\Work\bitbucket\PluralSight\proj1 [work2]>
```

I have uninstalled/reinstalled msysgit.  I get the same results in PowerShell and cmd.exe.

### Original Post

```
[work]> git rebase master
fatal: 'rebase' appears to be a git
command, but we were not   able to execute it.
Maybe git-rebase is broken?
```

Just reinstalled mSysGit on Win7x64.  The PATH now includes:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong?  I searched on GitHub, but didn't find any info there...

Comment: Which command shell are you using there? PowerShell? I suspect you may have another sh.exe on you system which is getting used instead of the one shipped with Git for Windows. If so, try removing the path for Git\bin and just use Git\cmd. The Git\cmd\git.exe wrapper sets the environment so that the git programs find the utilities that were shipped with git first.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  However, Git\cmd comes before Git\bin.  I'll try removing Git\bin anyway.

Comment: git.exe is an external : C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe.   Same result in both PowerShell and cmd.exe (and tcc.exe).

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is quite old but I ran into a similar problem. It may help someone else.
To avoid problems with MinGW make, I had to rename `sh.exe` to ensure it was not in the path. After that, commands like `git rebase` were not working anymore giving the same error as in the question:

```
fatal: 'rebase' appears to be a git
command, but we were not   able to execute it.
Maybe git-rebase is broken?
```

As soon as I restored `sh.exe`, `git rebase` restarted to work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you find `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-rebase` which is a shell script?
It should be there in order to work.

Comment: Yes, that (C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-rebase) exists.  'git rebase' (and related ops) is working on one computer, but not another; trying to figure out what's different.  Strange, since I'm pretty sure I used the same install procedure.

Comment: I discovered that I was missing the entry for the path `C:\Program Files\Git\bin' in the path variable.  Apparently my path variable has reached it's limit so I couldn't even enter manually.  I ended up creating a separate variable... named it GITA and added that variable to the path entries.  Reason I added path git/binis because that's where the sh.exe resides. Apparently that is what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not definitive (it doesn't explain why git is working on one of my computers but not the other), but it does provide some insight into what might be going on: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/VrQLAgQwJHM

I have installed the portable version, added it to my path, and git is working as expected again.