# fatal: 'stash'. Maybe git-stash is broken?

Tags: git

There are changes to the indexed file. Decided to hide changes typing

```
git stash
```

Result:

```
fatal: 'stash' appears to be a git command, but we were not 
able to execute it. Maybe git-stash is broken?
```

How to fix?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346755/maybe-git-rebase-is-broken

Comment: Which OS, which git version?

Comment: @JohnZwinck This is different.

Comment: @Schnouki Windows 8.1, git-2.12.0-64-bit